# Is there a way I can get the coefs_ attribute before fitting sklearn MLPRegressor?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, neural-network

I'm new in machine learning and I'm practicing to make a neural network that approximates functions. For just the purpose of learning and see the states of the neural network I'd like to know the initial coefficients of the neural network. Here is a reproducible example:

```
import sklearn.neural_network as sknn
import numpy as np

LIMIT = 10.0

# Function I want to approximate
def funcion(x):
    if x<3:
        return 0
    if x>7:
        return 12
    return 3*(x-3)

X = np.array([])    
Y = np.array([])    

# Data training set
for x in np.arange(0.0, LIMIT, 1.5):
    X = np.append(X, x)
    Y = np.append(Y, funcion(x))

X = np.append(X,10)
Y = np.append(Y, funcion(10))

X = np.reshape(X, (-1,1))

nn = sknn.MLPRegressor(
    learning_rate_init=0.01, 
    learning_rate = 'constant',
    activation='logistic',  
    hidden_layer_sizes=(2,1),
    max_iter=1,
    random_state=None)


print('coefficients: ', nn.coefs_)  # THIS GIVES THE ERROR

nn.fit(X, Y)
```

Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "aproxFun2.py", line 41, in <module>
    print('coefficients: ', nn.coefs_)
AttributeError: 'MLPRegressor' object has no attribute 'coefs_'
```

It prints the data whenever I call the `nn.coefs_` *after* I call the `nn.fit(X, Y)` function, but I want to know the values before fitting.

Comment: Sorry dude, I'm new at using this platform as you can see. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: cool - just remember to use some common sense :)

Answer (score 1):

coefs_ is not initialized before calling `_initialize(self, y, layer_units)` ( in fit() ) , so I guess you can't.

Answer (score 0):

Reading the source code ([link](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/a24c8b46/sklearn/neural_network/multilayer_perceptron.py#L300)), the initialization is performed iteratively over all layers with the following method:

```
def _init_coef(self, fan_in, fan_out):
    if self.activation == 'logistic':
        # Use the initialization method recommended by
        # Glorot et al.
        init_bound = np.sqrt(2. / (fan_in + fan_out))
    elif self.activation in ('identity', 'tanh', 'relu'):
        init_bound = np.sqrt(6. / (fan_in + fan_out))
    else:
        # this was caught earlier, just to make sure
        raise ValueError("Unknown activation function %s" %
                         self.activation)

    coef_init = self._random_state.uniform(-init_bound, init_bound,
                                           (fan_in, fan_out))
    intercept_init = self._random_state.uniform(-init_bound, init_bound,
                                                fan_out)
    return coef_init, intercept_init
```

where `fan_in` and `fan_out` represent size of the input resp. output layer.

So you can actually figure out the initialization for a fixed random state by running the above code.

Regarding the initialization itself, the weights are sampled from a uniform distribution centered at 0. The support of the distribution is a function of output and input layer sizes. See the reference paper 
[Understanding the difficulty of training deep feedforward neural networks](http://proceedings.mlr.press/v9/glorot10a/glorot10a.pdf) for more details.